# tikzpicture: put some ybars behind other ybars

Tags: tikz-pgf

I guess this is an easy question, but could not find any answer that was helping.

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
month;t1;t2;t3;t4
1;2.0;4.0;3.0;5.0
2;3.0;5.0;4.0;6.0
3;4.0;6.0;5.0;4.0
4;5.0;7.0;6.0;5.0
5;6.0;8.0;7.0;9.0
6;7.0;9.0;8.0;10.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{temp.dat}{\temp}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,bar width=5pt
    ]             
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x=month,y=t1] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x=month,y=t2] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=blue] table [x=month,y=t3] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=black] table [x=month,y=t4] {\temp};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want t2 to appear behind t1 and t4 behind t3. I know ybar shift, but I dont want to shift every single ybar by hand, my original code has got some more ybars. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'behind'? There are several samples where t3 is larger than t4, would you want t4 hidden in those occasions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgfplots` knows the key `bar shift auto`, which is used for grouping the bars of multiple bar plots. In the manual on page 83 its definition is shown (I also copied it into the code for reference). Based on this here are some redefinitions for pairwise overlapping bars.

Note: to overdraw t2 with t1 and t4 with t3 the order of the plots had to be changed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
month;t1;t2;t3;t4
1;2.0;4.0;3.0;5.0
2;3.0;5.0;4.0;6.0
3;4.0;6.0;5.0;4.0
4;5.0;7.0;6.0;5.0
5;6.0;8.0;7.0;9.0
6;7.0;9.0;8.0;10.0
\end{filecontents*}

% original from the manual
%\pgfplotsset{
%    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
%        /pgf/bar shift={%
%            % total width = n*w + (n-1)*skip
%            % -> subtract half for centering
%            -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype*\pgfplotbarwidth + (\numplotsofactualtype-1)*(#1)) +
%            % the ’0.5*w’ is for centering
%            (.5+\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)
%        },
%    },
%}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{temp.dat}{\temp}

% full overlap, t2 must be drawn before t1 and t4 before t3
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={%
            % total width = n/2*w + ((n/2)-1)*skip
            % -> subtract half for centering
            -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype/2*\pgfplotbarwidth + ((\numplotsofactualtype/2)-1)*(#1)) +
            % the ’0.5*w’ is for centering
            (.5+round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth + (round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*(#1)
        },
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title=full overlap,
    ybar,bar width=5pt
    ]             
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x=month,y=t2] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x=month,y=t1] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=black] table [x=month,y=t4] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=blue] table [x=month,y=t3] {\temp};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% half overlap, front on the left
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={%
            % total width = n/2*w*1.5 + ((n/2)-1)*skip 
            % need to add 0.5*skip here to correct centering
            % -> subtract half for centering
            -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype/2*\pgfplotbarwidth*1.5 + (\numplotsofactualtype/2)*(#1)) +
            % the ’0.5*w’ is for centering
            (.5+round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth*1.5 +
            iseven(\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth*0.5 +
            (round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*(#1)
        },
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={half overlap, front on left},
    ybar,bar width=5pt
    ]             
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x=month,y=t2] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x=month,y=t1] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=black] table [x=month,y=t4] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=blue] table [x=month,y=t3] {\temp};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% half overlap, front on the right
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={%
            % total width = n/2*w*1.5 + ((n/2)-1)*skip
            % need to add 0.5*skip here to correct centering
            % -> subtract half for centering
            -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype/2*\pgfplotbarwidth*1.5 + (\numplotsofactualtype/2)*(#1)) +
            % the ’0.5*w’ is for centering
            (.5+round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*\pgfplotbarwidth*1.5 +
            isodd(\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth*0.5 +
            (round((\plotnumofactualtype+1)/2)-1)*(#1)
        },
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={half overlap, front on right},
    ybar,bar width=5pt
    ]             
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x=month,y=t2] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x=month,y=t1] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=black] table [x=month,y=t4] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=blue] table [x=month,y=t3] {\temp};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first example was what I was aiming for, the second example is why I love this platform so much. I am going to use the second one.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want some bars behind others, why not go to 3D? (Note that if you play around with that, you may have to readjust `\gconv`, but you will get told to which value you are supposed to set it.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
month;t1;t2;t3;t4
1;2.0;4.0;3.0;5.0
2;3.0;5.0;4.0;6.0
3;4.0;6.0;5.0;4.0
4;5.0;7.0;6.0;5.0
5;6.0;8.0;7.0;9.0
6;7.0;9.0;8.0;10.0
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{temp.dat}{\resulttable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[% from section 4.6.4 of the pgfplotsmanual
        view={20}{40},
        width=320pt,
        height=280pt,
        z buffer=none,
        xmin=0,xmax=6,
        ymin=0.5,ymax=2,
        zmin=0,zmax=24,
        enlargelimits=upper,
        xtick={1,...,6},
        xticklabels={1,...,6},
        ztick={0,10,20},
        zticklabels={0,5,10}, % here one has to "cheat"
        ytick=\empty,
        % meaning that one has to put labels which are the actual value 
        % divided by 2. This is because the bars will be centered at these
        % values
        xtick=data,
        xlabel={month},
        ylabel={~},
        zlabel={$t$},
        minor tick num=1,
        point meta=explicit,
        colormap name=hot,
        scatter/use mapped color={
            draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color!70},
        execute at begin plot={}            
        ]
\def\gconv{8.57727}     
\path let \p1=($(axis cs:0,0,1)-(axis cs:0,0,0)$) in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\conv}{2*\y1}
\ifx\gconv\conv
\typeout{z-scale\space good!}
\else
\typeout{Kindly\space consider\space setting\space the\space 
        prefactor\space of\space z\space to\space \conv}
\fi     
        };
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{0.18}         
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
\gconv*z \as \myz}, % you'll get told how to adjust the prefactor
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=8pt},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=2pt},%
scatter,only marks,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{month}-\DeltaX},y expr={1.6},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{t3}},
 meta expr={3}
        ] \resulttable;
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
\gconv*z \as \myz}, % you'll get told how to adjust the prefactor
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=8pt},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=2pt},%
scatter,only marks,y=1,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{month}+\DeltaX},y expr={1.6},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{t4}},
 meta expr={4}
        ] \resulttable;              
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
\gconv*z \as \myz}, % you'll get told how to adjust the prefactor
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=8pt},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=2pt},%
scatter,only marks,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{month}-\DeltaX},y expr={1},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{t1}},
 meta expr={1}
        ] \resulttable;
\addplot3 [visualization depends on={
\gconv*z \as \myz}, % you'll get told how to adjust the prefactor
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size z=\myz},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size x=8pt},%
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/pgfplots/cube/size y=2pt},%
scatter,only marks,y=1,
mark=cube*,mark size=5,opacity=1]
 table[x expr={\thisrow{month}+\DeltaX},y expr={1},z
 expr={1*\thisrow{t2}},
 meta expr={2}
        ] \resulttable;     
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to answer, but I don't think this should be used in a scientific context. Anyways it might be a good Inspiration for others.

Comment: @FelixPhl I do not share your opinion "I don't think this should be used in a scientific contex".

Comment: Problem in my opinion is, that you cannot compare the first and the second row. Due to it being 3D, you cannot "see", wether the yellow or the red bar is highger for example.

Comment: @FelixPhl Of course you can. To guide the eye, you could move them closer to each other and also make them transparent. Just set `ymin=-2,ymax=8,` in the axis options.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Max Snippe some questions remain. But this could give you a starting point.

I used the `x expr` and `bar shift = 0pt` options to manually defined the requested shifts.

The first `tikzpicture` is the direct application, while the second shows a way to generalize the shifting for larger datasets.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
month;t1;t2;t3;t4
1;2.0;4.0;3.0;5.0
2;3.0;5.0;4.0;6.0
3;4.0;6.0;5.0;4.0
4;5.0;7.0;6.0;5.0
5;6.0;8.0;7.0;9.0
6;7.0;9.0;8.0;10.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{temp.dat}{\temp}

% Manual application of shifts to hide bars behind previous ones
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,bar width=5pt,bar shift=0pt
    ]             
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x expr = \thisrow{month}-0.15,y=t1] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x expr = \thisrow{month}-0.15,y=t2] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=blue] table [x expr = \thisrow{month}+0.15,y=t3] {\temp};
     \addplot [fill=black] table [x expr = \thisrow{month}+0.15,y=t4] {\temp};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Generalization using \foreach loop on indices and shift values
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,bar width=5pt,bar shift=0pt
    ]             
    \foreach \ind/\shift [evaluate=\ind as \indd using int(\ind+1)] in {1/-0.15,3/0.15}{
     \addplot [fill=cyan]  table [x expr = \thisrow{month}+\shift,y=t\ind] {\temp}; 
     \addplot [fill=gray] table [x expr = \thisrow{month}+\shift,y=t\indd] {\temp};
     }
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```